# Find value before a searched value in a delimited string

Tags: php, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, text-extraction

I have the following text string: **"Gardening,Landscaping,Football,3D Modelling"**

I need PHP to pick out the string ***before*** the phrase, "**Football**".

So, no matter the size of the haystack, the code will always scan for the phrase '**Football**' and retrieve the text immediately before it.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
$haystack = "Swimming,Astronomy,Gardening,Rugby,Landscaping,Football,3D Modelling";
$find = "Football";
$string = magicFunction($find, $haystack);
echo $string; // $string would = 'Landscaping'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$terms = explode(',', $array);
$index = array_search('Football', $terms);
$indexBefore = $index - 1;

if (!isset($terms[$indexBefore])) {
    trigger_error('No element BEFORE');
} else {
    echo $terms[$indexBefore];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//PHP 5.4
echo explode(',Football', $array)[0]

//PHP 5.3-
list($string) = explode(',Football', $array);
echo $string;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it doesn't remove the content **BEFORE** the phrase 'Football'. So, my $string becomes `Swimming,Astronomy,Gardening,Rugby,Landscaping`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Oh, by "pick out" I thought you meant "get" not "remove."  Just use `[1]` or `list(,$string)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array("Swimming","Astronomy","Gardening","Rugby","Landscaping","Football","3D" "Modelling");
$find = "Football";
$string = getFromOffset($find, $array);
echo $string; // $string would = 'Landscaping'

function getFromOffset($find, $array, $offset = -1)
{
    $id = array_search($find, $array);
    if (!$id)
        return $find.' not found';
    if (isset($array[$id + $offset]))
        return $array[$id + $offset];
    return $find.' is first in array';
}
```

You can also set the offset to be different from 1 previous.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the act of splitting the delimited string into an array and just use a regular expression to extract the word prior to the searched word.

`preg_quote()` is not actually needed with your sample search term, but is a good idea if the term comes from an untrusted source.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PAifo))

```
var_export(
    preg_match(
        '#[^,]+(?=,' . preg_quote($find) . ')#',
        $string,
        $m
    )
    ? $m[0]
    : null
);
```

If the searched term is not found or does not have a preceding term, then `null` will be returned.  If you need to enforce full-word matching, you can [add `(?:$|,)` to the end of the lookahead](https://3v4l.org/neZQD).